# Por vs para when discussing number of times

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

Which one would be the preposition of choice when discussing the number of times something happened? Examples:

*I saw her for the third time.
She is visiting me for the first time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **por** in most of the cases.

> *La he visto por tercera vez.*
>
> *Me visita por primera vez.*

I cannot think of any case where you would use **para** for a number of times type of sentence.

Comment: “por tercera vez” or “por la tercera vez”? Any reason for omitting the article here?

Comment: I think you would use either the article of the preposition but not both. "Es la tercera vez que la veo" / "Es la tercera vez que me visita"

Comment: So would it also be correct to say, “La he visto la tercera vez.”?

Comment: That sentence is not correct. You should either say "La he visto por tercera vez" or "Es la tercera vez que la veo". The first "La" refers to you "Yo la he visto ..." and the "por" is going to qualify the time, as a number, as a chance "la he visto por casualidad". But using twice "la" is not correct, at least on this example.

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you refer to time at all, you will use `por`.

If you were to say

`Escribí una caricatura para tres minutos`

It would suggest that you drew a cartoon FOR 3 minutes, not as in time, but rather, for, as in a gift.  In other words you would be drawing a cartoon as a favor to 3 Minutes, as if it were a person/business/entity/etcetera... named "3 Minutes"